# How to position a textView relative to an image in Android

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-relativelayout

I'm developing an app for cars where the user is able to register the car's plate number. In the home screen I want to show the image of a car with the user's plate (which is a textView). The problem is, whenever I fix it for some resolutions it stops working on others, does anyone know how fix this?

Here's my xml code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context="com.bsbapps.happycars.HomeFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/notify"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="callSubscribe"
            android:text="@string/subscribe"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="center">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/car_image"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/car"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="jfk-4548"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/car_image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And here's the image if anyone wants to reproduce exactly what I'm having:

[image]

The result I get is (on Nexus 9):

[image]

And (on Nexus 5):

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The problem is, whenever I fix it for some resolutions it stops working on others, does anyone know how fix this?

If you want to do it dimension-based, you should use [multiple "dimens" files](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html).

Change

```
android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
```

to

```
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/someDimensionName"
```

and then declare `someDimensionName` in multiple dimens.xml files under resource folders named `values-<screen-resolution>`:

values/dimens.xml (default)

```
<dimen name="someDimensionName">30dp</dimen>
```

values-sw600dp/dimens.xml (large screens)

```
<dimen name="someDimensionName">60dp</dimen>
```

(Exact `values-`size will vary; this is just an example. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for further details/size options.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I was hoping there was an easier way. For instance, in Unity, you can set a parent for the object and the child will keep the proportion no matter the scaling. But anyway, I'll follow your suggestion!